# Problem to install Epson l360 printer diver and scanner driver on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: drivers, apt, package-management, printing, scanner

have down loaded the epsonl360 printer driver from the epson web site, unfortunately when I tried to install through debian package installer it shows

```
error dependecny is not satisfiable:l sb>=3.2
```

I am in problem to install my printer what is the solution for it.
It is suggested I have seen that `lsb-compat_9.20161125_amd64.deb` should be down loaded from Debian web site, but I  can't found this type of software Please inform me what should do, I would like to inform you that I used Ubuntu23.04 and it works fine but after reinstallation of ubuntu23.04 it can't work. Next I have done the following command:-
have done as per your intruction the is as follows:
1)

```
$  uname -a
Linux ramendu-narayan-datta-AM1M-S2H 6.2.0-25-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jun 16 17:05:07 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

2. 

```
lsb_release -crid
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.04
Release:    23.04
Codename:   lunar
ramendu-narayan-datta@ramendu-narayan-datta-AM1M-S2H:~$
```

3. 

```
ramendu-narayan-datta@ramendu-narayan-datta-AM1M-S2H:~$  apt policy lsb
lsb:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
ramendu-narayan-datta@ramendu-narayan-datta-AM1M-S2H:~$
```

4. 

```
ramendu-narayan-datta@ramendu-narayan-datta-AM1M-S2H:~$ dpkg -l | grep -i epson
ramendu-narayan-datta@ramendu-narayan-datta-AM1M-S2H:~$
```

Problem not solved
)

```
ramendu-narayan-datta@ramendu-narayan-datta-AM1M-S2H:~$  apt policy lsb
lsb:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
ramendu-narayan-datta@ramendu-narayan-datta-AM1M-S2H:~$
```

4. 

```
ramendu-narayan-datta@ramendu-narayan-datta-AM1M-S2H:~$ dpkg -l | grep -i epson
ramendu-narayan-datta@ramendu-narayan-datta-AM1M-S2H:~$
```

Problem not solved
I request how can I resolve the problem

.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps CUPS already has a driver?

Access the CUPS (Common Unix Printing Sysyem) GUI by pointing your browser  to `http://localhost:631`.

You can detect, add, and manage printers from the `Admin` tab, and deal with individual printers from the `Printers` tab. You can set the system default printer.

From the command line,

`lpstat -t`

will show the total state of the printing system.